# How to make a Self-sizing UiImageView?

Tags: swift, ios-autolayout

I have a need for a simple QR Code class that I can re-use. I have created the class and it works, however manually setting the size constraints is not desired because it needs to adjust its size based on the DPI of the device. Here in this minimal example, I just use 100 as the sizing calculation code is not relevant (set to 50 in IB). Also I will have multiple QR Codes in different positions, which I will manage their positioning by IB. But at least I hope to be able to set the width and height constraints in code.

The below code shows a QR code, in the right size (set at runtime), but when the constraints are set to horizontally and vertically center it, it does not. Again, I don't want the size constraints in the IB, but I do want the position constraints in the IB

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class QrCodeView: UIImageView {
    var content:String = "test" {
        didSet {
            generateCode(content)
        }
    }
    lazy var filter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator")
    lazy var imageView = UIImageView()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:100, height:100)
        frame = CGRect(x:frame.origin.x, y:frame.origin.y, width:100, height:100)

    }

    func setup() {
        //translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        generateCode(content)


        addSubview(imageView)
        layoutIfNeeded()

    }

    func generateCode(_ string: String) {
        guard let filter = filter,
        let data = string.data(using: .isoLatin1, allowLossyConversion: false) else {
            return
        }

        filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")

        guard let ciImage = filter.outputImage else {
            return
        }
        let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 10, y: 10)
        let scaled = UIImage(ciImage: ciImage.transformed(by: transform))

        imageView.image = scaled
    }

}
```

Comment: This is a little unclear, as you say *"I just use 100 as the sizing calculation code is not relevant"* ... You also say *"The below code shows a QR code, in the right size (set at runtime), but when the constraints are set to horizontally and vertically center it, it does not."* ... It does not what? It doesn't size correctly? It doesn't position correctly? It doesn't show at all?

Comment: The initial placement is centered 50x50. When the code is executed, the size updates to 100x100 (yay) however it does not move, so the additional size does not cause a re-layout, and it ends up being too right and too low on the screen.

Comment: OK - the "native size" of the generated QRCode image will vary based on the encoded content. For example, a single character `A` results in a `23 x 23` image... a long string (such as your comment) produces a `63 x 63` image. So, your `CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 10, y: 10)` line can result in a `230 x 230` or `630 x 630` image. Is that your desired behavior? Or would you have a "target size" defined?

Comment: The QR code is to be machine read and needs to be 15x15mm, which I will take care of by sizing the CGRect, but it has to be positioned in the device's center. I cannot figure out how to size and have it centered at the same time.  The code above will size it correctly on my test device, but after sizing the code is not longer in the center.

Comment: Hmmm.... so, at run-time you're going to set the size of the imageView, and you want the QRCode image to fill the imageView?

Comment: No, I want the imageview to be sized to the QR code, ending up as 15x15mm, and I want that properly centered.

Comment: OK - but how are you determining the size of the QR code image?

Comment: I take the DPI of the device via LUT/calculation, and convert to the actual size in pixels for the display. Once that is set, I need it to be centered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're making this more complicated than need be...

Let's start with a simple `@IBDesignable UIImageView` subclass.

Start with a new project and add this code:

```
@IBDesignable
class MyImageView: UIImageView {

    // we'll use this later
    var myIntrinsicSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 100.0, height: 100.0)
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return myIntrinsicSize
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }
    
    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        setup()
        self.image = UIImage()
    }
    
    func setup() {
        backgroundColor = .green
        contentMode = .scaleToFill
    }

}
```

Now, in Storyboard, add a `UIImageView` to a view controller. Set its custom class to `MyImageView` and set Horizontal and Vertical Center constraints.

The image view should automatically size itself to `100 x 100`, centered in the view with a green background (we're just setting the background so we can see it):

[image]

Run the app, and you should see the same thing.

Now, add it as an `@IBOutlet` to a view controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var testImageView: MyImageView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        testImageView.myIntrinsicSize = CGSize(width: 300.0, height: 300.0)
    }
}
```

Run the app, and you will see a centered green image view, but now it will be `300 x 300` points instead of `100 x 100`.

The rest of your task is pretty much adding code to set this custom class's `.image` property once you've rendered the QRCode image.

Here's the custom class:

```
@IBDesignable
class QRCodeView: UIImageView {
    
    // so we can test changing the QRCode content in IB
    @IBInspectable
    var content:String = "test" {
        didSet {
            generateCode(content)
        }
    }
    
    var qrIntrinsicSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 100.0, height: 100.0)
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return qrIntrinsicSize
    }
    
    lazy var filter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator")
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }
    
    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        setup()
        generateCode(content)
    }
    
    func setup() {
        contentMode = .scaleToFill
    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        generateCode(content)
    }
    
    func generateCode(_ string: String) {
        guard let filter = filter,
            let data = string.data(using: .isoLatin1, allowLossyConversion: false) else {
                return
        }
        
        filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
        
        guard let ciImage = filter.outputImage else {
            return
        }
        
        let scX = bounds.width / ciImage.extent.size.width
        let scY = bounds.height / ciImage.extent.size.height

        let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scX, y: scY)

        let scaled = UIImage(ciImage: ciImage.transformed(by: transform))
        
        self.image = scaled
        
    }
    
}
```

In Storyboard / IB:

[image]

And here's an example view controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var qrCodeView: QRCodeView!
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        // calculate your needed size
        //  I'll assume it ended up being 240 x 240
        qrCodeView.qrIntrinsicSize = CGSize(width: 240.0, height: 240.0)
    }
    
}
```

---

**Edit**

Here's a modified `QRCodeView` class that will size itself to a (physical) 15x15 mm image.

I used `DeviceKit` from https://github.com/devicekit/DeviceKit to get the current device's `ppi`. See the comment to replace it with your own (assuming you are already using something else).

When this class is instantiated, it will:

- get the current device's ppi
- convert ppi to pixels-per-millimeter
- calculate 15 x pixels-per-millimeter
- convert based on screen scale
- update its intrinsic size

The `QRCodeView` (subclass of `UIImageView`) needs only position constraints... so you can use Top + Leading, Top + Trailing, Center X & Y, Bottom + CenterX, etc, etc.

```
@IBDesignable
class QRCodeView: UIImageView {
    
    @IBInspectable
    var content:String = "test" {
        didSet {
            generateCode(content)
        }
    }
    
    var qrIntrinsicSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 100.0, height: 100.0)
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return qrIntrinsicSize
    }
    
    lazy var filter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator")
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }
    
    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        setup()
        generateCode(content)
    }
    
    func setup() {
        contentMode = .scaleToFill
        
        // using DeviceKit from https://github.com/devicekit/DeviceKit
        // replace with your lookup code that gets
        //  the device's ppi
        let device = Device.current
        guard let ppi = device.ppi else { return }
        
        // convert to pixels-per-millimeter
        let ppmm = CGFloat(ppi) / 25.4
        // we want 15mm size
        let mm15 = 15.0 * ppmm
        // convert based on screen scale
        let mmScale = mm15 / UIScreen.main.scale
        // update our intrinsic size
        self.qrIntrinsicSize = CGSize(width: mmScale, height: mmScale)

    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        generateCode(content)
    }
    
    func generateCode(_ string: String) {
        guard let filter = filter,
            let data = string.data(using: .isoLatin1, allowLossyConversion: false) else {
                return
        }
        
        filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
        
        guard let ciImage = filter.outputImage else {
            return
        }
        
        let scX = bounds.width / ciImage.extent.size.width
        let scY = bounds.height / ciImage.extent.size.height

        let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scX, y: scY)

        let scaled = UIImage(ciImage: ciImage.transformed(by: transform))

        self.image = scaled
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I probably am making it harder than it needs to be :-) Does this mean that I can't have the QrCodeView size itself? Because that means that I have to have the ViewController set the size. I was hoping to avoid that, and have the size logic in the QrCodeView size logic in the class itself.

Comment: I think you're still not clear about *"QRCode size itself"*. The `CIFilter` generates an image based on the data encoded in the QRCode. For example, encoding the single letter `A` produces a `CIImage` with size extents of `23 x 23`. Encoding this comment will produce extents of somewhere around `63 x 63`. So... what do you want to do with that? If you want it to be `15x15 mm`, ***somewhere*** you have to calculate that size. Show your code for calculating `15x15 mm`.

Comment: @UserOneFourTwo - check the edit to my answer. Might give you what you're going for.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. I have a better understanding now. yes, I have a mechanism similar to device kit. That was not the challenge. Updating the size and still having it centered  was the challenge so I never included the size calculation itself because I prefer minimal examples. Thank you for all your help!